# How do I get my battle into TV Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

In *Clash Royale*, are there any specific rules they are using to select battles to show in TV Royale?

Like how many battles I played, how many battles I won, how long I have been playing *Clash Royale*, or how many trophies I have? Or is it just randomly selected?

**How do I get my battle into TV Royale?**

Answer (score 4):

From the [wiki](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/TV_Royale).

- A new TV Royale replay is added to each channel every hour, and a battle replay will disappear from TV Royale after 24 hours, so the maximum number of replays in a channel is 24.
- Generally, battles in TV Royale will be upset matches, three crown draws, unusual decks, and close calls except for the Legendary Arena (Arena 12) channel, which also includes many top player matches.
- TV Royale has 12 different channels, one for each Arena. This allows the player to view battles of different levels.

It seems like there are no set requirements, but based on a game per game basis.